# Setting up a Bayesian Model using Titanic data

Tags: bayesian, model

Trying to set up a Bayesian model using the Titanic data available online, specifically making inferences on the data using a Bayesian approach. I want to investigate how survival of a passenger is affected based on characteristics like sex (male and female; 2 levels) and passenger class (1st, 2nd, 3rd; 3 levels). The data denotes whether a passenger survives or not (1 or 0).

What I would like to find out

- Is survival of a passenger affected by a passenger's sex? For example: Is a passenger more likely to survive if they are a woman?
- Is survival of a passenger affected by passenger class? For example: Is a passenger from 1st class more likely to survive compared to a passenger in 3rd class?
- Is survival of a passenger affected by sex and passenger class together? Example: Is a man from 1st class more likely to survive than a woman from 3rd class?

I initially thought to set up priors and likelihood so that I can obtain a posterior distribution to make inferences on (following a Bayesian setup). But that was not a great approach. I also thought I could assume that survival followed a Binomial distribution (since the outcome was either 1 or 0) but that is not the case since the probability of survival for each passenger is not the same.

I think I am headed towards Bayesian inference on a logistic regression or a multilevel model. I have an idea of how this would be setup using frequentist methods, but Bayesian model setup is giving me a lot of trouble and I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: Your beta prior does not make *any* sense... From your description it seems that you do not fully understand the idea of Bayesian models and priors, so maybe you should start with some handbook on Bayesian inference..? Moreover, if things are unclear for you, maybe you should start with some more basic question to clear your concerns?

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: Thanks for your edits; they do improve the information about what you're doing somewhat but you still don't ask a specific enough question. Vague open-ended statement-type questions ("I don't know where to begin") aren't really suited to our format (See [how to ask a good question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), particularly in relation to search and research -- have you fitted a Bayesian GLM before? Have you fitted any GLM before?). Please identify a specific question and ask it/

Comment: Take the guessing out of your question; it detracts from the answer, which is use *regression*. It doesn't help your case to be asking things that amount to "Can I use a rubber ducky to float the Titanic?" Just ask "How do I take" 'such and such data' "and get an answer"

Answer (score 2):

The model $Y \sim \operatorname{Binomial} θ$ isn't sufficient for this problem because it postulates a probability of survival $θ$ that's the same for every passenger, and you want to examine how survival relates to per-passenger features, namely gender and class. The standard approach to this sort of problem, whether you prefer frequentist or Bayesian methods, is logistic regression. With a regression model, you could have gender and class as main effects and a gender-by-class interaction. So look into Bayesian inference on regression models, or just regression models in general if you're not already familiar with them.